# Blend MPMovieplayerController in background UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiview, mpmovieplayercontroller

As the title says, I was trying make so that the corners of my `MPMovieplayerController` go underneath my `UIView` background image, but I don't know how to obtain this effect. The effect I would like to obtain is similar to the one you can see in the image. The corners of the piece of paper are slid in the background, but I would like the tip of the paper to be seen. Can this be achieved through code? 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put that part that is supposed to hide your video view (I will refer to it as your Mask View) on top of the parent view, after you have added the video view to that parent view.

1. add video view to parent view
2. add mask view to parent view

The resulting view hierachy could look like the following:

`P`=Parent View
`V`=Video View
`M`=Mask View

top down view:

```
PPPPPPPP
PVVVVVVP
PMVVVVVP
PMMVVVVP
PPPPPPPP
```

left side view:

```
 MM
 VVVVVV
PPPPPPPP
```